# What to do when accidentally committed HUGE binary file / file with password as plain text?

Tags: git, binary, branch, git-filter-branch

I just needed to post an answer so everyone will know it and also to save it for my future mistakes.

If anyone here knows better solution / tips / advices on this, please, elaborate! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy thing - you wont need to cut out commits, just do:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch $files" HEAD
```

It will delete all the file occurrences in history. You can mention `$files` as single file or as bunch of them.

**Note** that it will create backup, so you will need to use this command with `-f` option in case when you need to run it more than one time.

man: [git-filter-branch(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html)

the idea belongs to [The Nuclear Option: filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#The-Nuclear-Option%3a-filter-branch)

Comment: Note that this option should be strongly avoided if you've got shared history. Also, if you've `push`ed **your passwords should be considered compromised and should all be changed**, even if you "go nuclear".